# soft blurry graphics on xbox 360 hooked to pc monitor

Tags: xbox-360, monitor

i bought an xbox 360 today and hooked it to my monitor with an hdmi cable. everything looks good except when i get into a game, (madden for example), the quality is softish kinda blurry, the characters and everything. heres my monitor: http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-21-inch...
I'm running at 1080p. Ive tried using different resolutions but it still has the same result
does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried another monitor or TV? What are the results?

Comment: Link doesn't work. Is it sold as a TV or a monitor?

Comment: If it's sold as a TV, I would check to make sure that it's in PC or Game mode, which disables various filters and effects intended to make movies and shows look better.

Answer (score -1):

Try a different monitor or TV and see what happens.
If the effect is the same try a different hdmi cable (they don't break easily but they are not indestructible)

If the problem isnt resolved, try a factory reset on the Xbox 360.

If this doesn't help I'm afraid you have a faulty hdmi port on the Xbox 360.
If you bought it from a store you can always try to see what the shop can do for you in terms of service like a replacement if that's still available.

If you bought it from lets say ebay I'm afraid they sold you a broken Xbox 360 and maybe you can pick it up with them but I guess thats the risk buying from ebay.

Comment: HDMI, being a digital signal, cannot degrade like this.  HDMI signal interference results in really obvious distortions.  It is most likely some sort of upscaling/downscaling or anti-aliasing effect.

Comment: @Nelson or its just a broken hdmi port. Or maybe the cable unpackaged wrong, or the cable got pulled while being stuck. There are more reason then just degrading for a cable

Comment: You're not really understanding the nature of a digital signal.  It is *impossible* to degrade like this.  It's sort of saying if you took half a credit card and used it, it'll only bill you for half the amount.  Digital signals are all or nothing.  You can't just make it fuzzy with interference.